# How does fread() in C work inside a for loop?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, fread, weather

I am new to C programming, but I need it to read some binary file which I describe below.

The India Meteorological Department (IMD) has provided historical weather data in .GRD files in their [website](http://cdsp.imdpune.gov.in/home_gridded_data.php#griddedTemp). They have also provided sample C code to read those files. From their sample C code, I have written the following code that extracts the daily minimum temperatures on 15 April 1980 recorded on a 31x31 grid over India.

```
/* This program reads binary data for 365/366 days and writes in ascii file. */ 
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
float t[31][31]; 
int i,j ,k; 
FILE *fin,*fout; 
fin = fopen("C:\\New folder\\Mintemp_MinT_1980.GRD","rb"); // Input file 
fout = fopen("C:\\New folder\\MINT15APR1980.TXT","w"); // Output file 
fprintf(fout,"Daily Minimum Tempereture for 15 April 1980\n");
if(fin == NULL) {
    printf("Can't open file");
    return 0;
}
if(fout == NULL) {
    printf("Can't open file");
    return 0; 
} 
for(k=0 ; k<366 ; k++) {
    fread(&t,sizeof(t),1,fin); 
    if(k == 105) {
        for(i=0 ; i < 31 ; i++) {
            fprintf(fout,"\n") ;
            for(j=0 ; j < 31 ; j++) 
                fprintf(fout,"%6.2f",t[i][j]);
        } 
    } 
} 
fclose(fin);
fclose(fout);
return 0; 
}
/* end of main */
```

The file `Mintemp_MinT_1980.GRD` can be downloaded from the [IMD website](http://cdsp.imdpune.gov.in/home_gridded_data.php#griddedTemp) by selecting the year as 1980 against Minimum Temperature.

What I don't understand is that how the fread() function actually works in the line `fread(&t,sizeof(t),1,fin)` within the loop `for(k=0 ; k<366 ; k++)`. In plain sight, the arguments of fread() here do not depend on the looping variable `k`, and so it should read the same data to the matrix `t[31][31]` for every `k`. However, I have checked that, surprisingly, the data extracted by this program are different for different values of `k` in the line `if(k == 105)`, i.e., the data extracted for `k == 105` and `k == 32` are different, for example.

I would very much appreciate if one can please explain the above.

Comment: The FILE * `fin` keeps track of its position in the file.  All file operations that read from the file will read from the current position and advance the position by the number of bytes read.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, thank you so much for replying! Could you please explain a bit more? In the program above, the value of the file pointer ```fin``` is first set in the line ```fin = fopen("C:\\New folder\\Mintemp_MinT_1980.GRD","rb");```. Did you mean that the value of ```fin``` is modified by the function fread() in the line ```fread(&t,sizeof(t),1,fin);```? In that case, does it mean that ```fread(&t,sizeof(t),1,fin);``` modifies the values of both the matrix ```t``` and the pointer ```fin```?

Comment: A couple of unrelated coding suggestions...  Don't use abolute paths when opening files if you can avoid it -- if you run the code from the directory the data is in, you can use a filename without a path.   When using fread, check its return value to make sure the data was actually read.  Then, if fread fails, either terminate the loop (with break, return, or exit) after the fread, or include the return value in the loop conditional.   That way, you don't get a mess of wrong output or an infinite loop if the file is shorter than you expect.

Comment: When `fread` is invoked, the value of `fin` is not changed, but the object pointed at by `fin` *is* modified.  A common implementation of a FILE * is a data structure that contains (among other things) a file descriptor, a buffer, and some metadata about the buffer.  When you call `fread` for the first time, data is read and stored in the buffer.  If you are making small reads, then quite likely the buffer will contain more data than your `fread `requested.  The metadata is updated so the next `fread` just returns previously read data from the buffer.

Comment: @WilliamPursell thanks a lot for the reply! It helped me understand the issue better than before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files contain sequential data.  All the file operators are based on the premise that whatever you do to a file, you'll generally be doing it in a sequential way.

So when you read data, and then read more data, you will be getting sequential chunks of the file.  The both the FILE datatype and the operating system itself do a number of things for you, including keeping track of your current position in the file and doing block buffering in memory to improve performance.

If you wanted to reread the same data over, or skip around in the file, you would need to use fseek() to change positions in the file before doing your next read.

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply! It is now a lot clear to me.

Comment: Give thanks with votes and accepting answers.  :)